# Why do I get NoClassDefFoundError when running JMockit Mocks?

Tags: java, junit, jmockit

I am running **JMockit** with **Junit 4** and get the error `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError.`

I want to test how my class (mycomponent) deals with values being returned from a 3rd party library static class. I am approaching this by creating the mocked class (mocked3rdpartycomponent) and then calling my mycomponent as below:

mytest->mycomponent->mocked3rdpartycomponent

The mocked class has the definition as follows. The mocked method and class is to substitute the before mentioned 3rd party library:

```
new Mockup<MockedClass>() {
  @Mock public ReturnType[] mockedMethod() {
    ReturnType[] ni = {null};
    return ni;
  }
}

Mycomponent mc = new MyComponent();
```

When I run my test class I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: mockit/internal/state/TestRun
at <MockedClass.mockedMethod>(MockedClass.java)
at <MyComponent>.<init>
caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mockit.internal.state.TestRun
```

**Edit:** In addition to this, if I try to step over the call in the Unit Under Test which should call my fake, a screen appears which states that source code for Junit cannot be found.

**Edit:** The third party library is also native with some static methods.

Does anybody know what this could be caused by?

My environment is Eclipse Mars 4.5.0, JUnit 4.10, JMockit 1.19.

Thanks!

Comment: Check that you don't have any older version of jmockit.jar or jmockit-coverage.jar in your runtime classpath. Other than that, I have no idea what could cause the error (unless the jmockit jar has been corrupted somehow).

Comment: Thanks for your response. Could it be that I'm trying to call the mocked class from an unmocked class? I.e. calling MockedClass from MyComponent?

Comment: No, since that is what tests do most of the time (calling mocked code from the code under test).

Comment: Infact if I could understand what the error means it would probably help a lot! Is the error specific? Or is it masking another error? This error only occurs when I attempt to make a call to the library which would result in a call to my mock (fake). It doesn't matter whether the mocked call is static or otherwise.

Comment: The other thing that may be worth mentioning is that the operating system is 64 bit, but the library I am trying to use is 32 bit. Would JMockit care about that?

Comment: Update. I have tried the this on a 32 bit operating system and the results are the same. I have however attached the Junit sources so that I can see the error. It's calling ReflectiveCallable and throwing e.getTargetException().

Comment: Sorry, but nothing of what you wrote is of any help. I still have no idea how I could reproduce the problem. And without being able to reproduce it, I cannot possibly identify the root cause of the failure.

Comment: Would you be able to point me to what the error could mean though? What typically causes NoClassDefFoundError: mockit/internal/state/TestRun ?

Comment: Nothing causes this error, as far as I know. You seem to be the only user seeing it.

Comment: Hey @jdie8274j any luck I am seeing the same issue, do you want to share the solution.