# Java Refactoring Strategy for Legacy Code

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mocking, refactoring

I have been asked to unit test some legacy code.

Currently, the code is tightly coupled with a 3rd party library both in terms of method calls and types used.

My first thought is to stub the 3rd party library (using an appropriate mocking framework) such that I can easily test the code of interest rather than the 3rd party library. However, to do this, I need to refactor some of the code so that the code of interest is isolated from the external library dependency.

My initial thought was to extract an interface and use a wrapper to make calls to the library. However, to entirely decouple the library I need to remove library specific types too, not just the method calls e.g.

```
LibrarySpecificType[] myVar = wrappedLibrary.DoX();
```

Although I have wrapped my library call in the above example, it still returns a library specific type, so it is still somewhat coupled.

How do I get around this? What is the best strategy to refactor the code to enable this?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand the need to remove the library in order to test the project. When you write a test mock any part (with mockito for exemple) you don't want to test.

Comment: I have found with JMockit that I can't create a fake for a 3rd party library.  Potentially because it doesn't have the source for the library. I also felt that the design would be better if the calls were wrapped so that it reduces the coupling on the library.

Comment: You don't need any source code to fake behavior ! If so change to another mock framework. You will need to refactor a lot before doing what you are supposed to do which is writing unit test.

Comment: JMockit does not use or require source code for anything (unless we were talking about the code coverage tool). To fake a type `T` from a 3rd party library you create a `MockUp<T>` for it. If you tried that and it didn't work, then post a separate question with enough information that the problem can be reproduced by others.

Comment: Thank you for you response Rogério - I think you're the man to help me! I previously posted this question without any luck: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32994290/why-do-i-get-noclassdeffounderror-when-running-jmockit-mocks .

Comment: If you could just provide me with some ideas on where to look for the problem it would be much appreciated. I have no problem with syntax. I understand how to use JMockit as I've used it in other tests without any problems. I suspect it's either a problem with the library I'm trying to test which resides in a Jar file, or my project setup. I am currently using Eclipse from an Ant Build file. The build file specifies how the code is compiled etc.I'll update the other post with additional information.

Answer (score 0):

1. I agree with you that producing a facade for the third party lib is a good idea. Then talk to this facade and not the 3rd party lib. So the only place the lib is referred to is in your facade.
2. The issue with the LibrarySpecificType is a bit more problematic. Again you could wrap them but would this help? Not sure
3. As for testing. I would use mockito/powermockito. You can tell it to return a mock (of LibrarySpecificType) from the mock of your Library and test this way. Obviously having a mock return a mock is a sign of bad design which in this case points the finger at LibrarySpecificType

Comment: Hi Lawrence, thanks for your response. How would you go about wrapping a return value?

Comment: Creating a facade for the 3rd party library may very well be a good idea (provided it simplifies client code, as that's what a facade is for), but ideally we should have a regression testing suite *before* doing that. Two options then: a) integration tests with no mocking/faking, or b) isolated unit tests which mock or fake the 3rd party lib. Option b can be implemented with PowerMock or JMockit (using mocks), or with JMockit (using fakes).