# Using JMockit with Tycho

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jmockit, tycho

I have several Eclipse Plugin-Projects which I want to compile using Maven & Tycho. The project can be found at [github](https://github.com/ChristophLu/maventest). There you see three projects with their `pom.xml` files. With that I aim to run unit test using JMockit.

To start Maven, I switch into the `maven.parent` directory and execute `mvn clean verify` which produces the following output:

```
D:\maven-test\maventest.parent>mvn clean verify
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Computing target platform for MavenProject: maventest:maventest:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT @ D:\maven-test\maventest\pom.xml
[INFO] Adding repository ....censored....
[INFO] Adding repository ....censored....
[INFO] Resolving dependencies of MavenProject: maventest:maventest:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT @ D:\maven-test\maventest\pom.xml
[INFO] Resolving class path of MavenProject: maventest:maventest:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT @ D:\maven-test\maventest\pom.xml
[INFO] Computing target platform for MavenProject: maventest:test.maventest:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT @ D:\maven-test\test.maventest\pom.xml
[INFO] Resolving dependencies of MavenProject: maventest:test.maventest:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT @ D:\maven-test\test.maventest\pom.xml
[INFO] Resolving class path of MavenProject: maventest:test.maventest:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT @ D:\maven-test\test.maventest\pom.xml
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO]
[INFO] maventest.parent
[INFO] maventest
[INFO] test.maventest
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building maventest.parent 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ maventest.parent ---
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building maventest 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ maventest ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- tycho-packaging-plugin:0.24.0:build-qualifier (default-build-qualifier) @ maventest ---
[INFO] The project's OSGi version is 1.0.0.201512010744
[INFO]
[INFO] --- tycho-packaging-plugin:0.24.0:validate-id (default-validate-id) @ maventest ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- tycho-packaging-plugin:0.24.0:validate-version (default-validate-version) @ maventest ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:resources (default-resources) @ maventest ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\maven-test\maventest\src\main\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- tycho-compiler-plugin:0.24.0:compile (default-compile) @ maventest ---
[INFO] Compiling 2 source files to D:\maven-test\maventest\target\classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:testResources (default-testResources) @ maventest ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\maven-test\maventest\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- target-platform-configuration:0.24.0:target-platform (default-target-platform) @ maventest ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- tycho-packaging-plugin:0.24.0:package-plugin (default-package-plugin) @ maventest ---
[INFO] Building jar: D:\maven-test\maventest\target\maventest-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- tycho-p2-plugin:0.24.0:p2-metadata-default (default-p2-metadata-default) @ maventest ---
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building test.maventest 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ test.maventest ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- tycho-packaging-plugin:0.24.0:build-qualifier (default-build-qualifier) @ test.maventest ---
[INFO] The project's OSGi version is 1.0.0.201512010744
[INFO]
[INFO] --- tycho-packaging-plugin:0.24.0:validate-id (default-validate-id) @ test.maventest ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- tycho-packaging-plugin:0.24.0:validate-version (default-validate-version) @ test.maventest ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:resources (default-resources) @ test.maventest ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\maven-test\test.maventest\src\main\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- tycho-compiler-plugin:0.24.0:compile (default-compile) @ test.maventest ---
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to D:\maven-test\test.maventest\target\classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:testResources (default-testResources) @ test.maventest ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\maven-test\test.maventest\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- target-platform-configuration:0.24.0:target-platform (default-target-platform) @ test.maventest ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- tycho-packaging-plugin:0.24.0:package-plugin (default-package-plugin) @ test.maventest ---
[INFO] Building jar: D:\maven-test\test.maventest\target\test.maventest-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- tycho-p2-plugin:0.24.0:p2-metadata-default (default-p2-metadata-default) @ test.maventest ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- tycho-surefire-plugin:0.24.0:test (default-test) @ test.maventest ---
[INFO] Expected eclipse log file: D:\maven-test\test.maventest\target\work\data\.metadata\.log
[INFO] Command line:
        [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk8\jre\bin\java.exe, -Dosgi.noShutdown=false, -Dosgi.os=win32, -Dosgi.ws=win32, -Dosgi.arch=x86_64, -javaagent:D:\maven-test\org.jmockit_1.20.0.jar, -Dosgi.clean=true,
 -jar, C:\Users\cludwig\.m2\repository\p2\osgi\bundle\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher\1.3.100.v20150511-1540\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher-1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar, -data, D:\maven-test\test.maventest\t
arget\work\data, -install, D:\maven-test\test.maventest\target\work, -configuration, D:\maven-test\test.maventest\target\work\configuration, -application, org.eclipse.tycho.surefire.osgibooter.headles
stest, -testproperties, D:\maven-test\test.maventest\target\surefire.properties]

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running test.maventest.Foo_UnitTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.118 sec <<< FAILURE! - in test.maventest.Foo_UnitTest
initializationError(test.maventest.Foo_UnitTest)  Time elapsed: 0.002 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.VerifyError: null
        at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.redefineClasses0(Native Method)
        at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.redefineClasses(InstrumentationImpl.java:170)
        at mockit.internal.startup.Startup.redefineMethods(Startup.java:242)
        at mockit.internal.startup.Startup.redefineMethods(Startup.java:236)
        at mockit.internal.mockups.MockClassSetup.applyClassModifications(MockClassSetup.java:134)
        at mockit.internal.mockups.MockClassSetup.redefineMethodsInClassHierarchy(MockClassSetup.java:91)
        at mockit.internal.mockups.MockClassSetup.redefineMethods(MockClassSetup.java:76)
        at mockit.MockUp.redefineMethods(MockUp.java:239)
        at mockit.MockUp.redefineClassOrImplementInterface(MockUp.java:221)
        at mockit.MockUp.<init>(MockUp.java:130)
        at mockit.integration.junit4.internal.RunNotifierDecorator.<init>(RunNotifierDecorator.java:21)
        at mockit.internal.startup.JMockitInitialization.loadInternalStartupMocksForJUnitIntegration(JMockitInitialization.java:35)
        at mockit.internal.startup.JMockitInitialization.initialize(JMockitInitialization.java:26)
        at mockit.internal.startup.Startup.applyStartupMocks(Startup.java:72)
        at mockit.internal.startup.Startup.reapplyStartupMocks(Startup.java:124)
        at mockit.internal.startup.Startup.getInstrumentation(Startup.java:188)
        at mockit.internal.startup.Startup.initializeIfPossible(Startup.java:198)
        at mockit.integration.junit4.JMockit.<clinit>(JMockit.java:21)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
        at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
        at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
        at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
        at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
        at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
        at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:262)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:124)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray2(ReflectionUtils.java:208)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:82)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.surefire.osgibooter.OsgiSurefireBooter.run(OsgiSurefireBooter.java:91)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.surefire.osgibooter.HeadlessTestApplication.run(HeadlessTestApplication.java:21)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.callMethodWithException(EclipseAppContainer.java:587)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:198)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1488)


Results :

Tests in error:
  Foo_UnitTest.initializationError ╗ Verify

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] maventest.parent ................................... SUCCESS [  0.219 s]
[INFO] maventest .......................................... SUCCESS [  4.227 s]
[INFO] test.maventest ..................................... FAILURE [  4.320 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 19.972 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-12-01T08:44:14+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 45M/405M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-surefire-plugin:0.24.0:test (default-test) on project test.maventest: There are test failures.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Please refer to D:\maven-test\test.maventest\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :test.maventest
```

If I remove the `-javaagent` in the parents POM, then I get another exception:

```
Running test.maventest.Foo_UnitTest
JMockit: Reinitializing under custom class loader org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader@1cbb87f3[org.jmockit:1.20.0(id=87)]
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:386)
        at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallAgentmain(InstrumentationImpl.java:411)
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError
        at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.redefineClasses0(Native Method)
        at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.redefineClasses(InstrumentationImpl.java:170)
        at mockit.internal.startup.Startup.redefineMethods(Startup.java:242)
        at mockit.internal.startup.Startup.redefineMethods(Startup.java:236)
        at mockit.internal.mockups.MockClassSetup.applyClassModifications(MockClassSetup.java:134)
        at mockit.internal.mockups.MockClassSetup.redefineMethodsInClassHierarchy(MockClassSetup.java:91)
        at mockit.internal.mockups.MockClassSetup.redefineMethods(MockClassSetup.java:76)
        at mockit.MockUp.redefineMethods(MockUp.java:239)
        at mockit.MockUp.redefineClassOrImplementInterface(MockUp.java:221)
        at mockit.MockUp.<init>(MockUp.java:130)
        at mockit.integration.junit4.internal.RunNotifierDecorator.<init>(RunNotifierDecorator.java:21)
        at mockit.internal.startup.JMockitInitialization.loadInternalStartupMocksForJUnitIntegration(JMockitInitialization.java:35)
        at mockit.internal.startup.JMockitInitialization.initialize(JMockitInitialization.java:26)
        at mockit.internal.startup.Startup.applyStartupMocks(Startup.java:72)
        at mockit.internal.startup.Startup.reapplyStartupMocks(Startup.java:124)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at mockit.internal.util.MethodReflection.invoke(MethodReflection.java:94)
        at mockit.internal.util.MethodReflection.invoke(MethodReflection.java:159)
        at mockit.internal.startup.Startup.reinitializeJMockitUnderCustomClassLoader(Startup.java:118)
        at mockit.internal.startup.Startup.agentmain(Startup.java:101)
        ... 6 more
java.lang.IllegalStateException: com.sun.tools.attach.AgentInitializationException: Agent JAR loaded but agent failed to initialize
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:262)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:124)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray2(ReflectionUtils.java:208)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:82)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.surefire.osgibooter.OsgiSurefireBooter.run(OsgiSurefireBooter.java:91)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.surefire.osgibooter.HeadlessTestApplication.run(HeadlessTestApplication.java:21)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.callMethodWithException(EclipseAppContainer.java:587)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:198)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1488)
Caused by: com.sun.tools.attach.AgentInitializationException: Agent JAR loaded but agent failed to initialize
        ... 26 more
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.382 sec <<< FAILURE! - in test.maventest.Foo_UnitTest
test_value(test.maventest.Foo_UnitTest)  Time elapsed: 0.045 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid place to record expectations
        at test.maventest.Foo_UnitTest$1.<init>(Foo_UnitTest.java:33)
        at test.maventest.Foo_UnitTest.getFoo(Foo_UnitTest.java:33)
        at test.maventest.Foo_UnitTest.test_value(Foo_UnitTest.java:25)


Results :

Tests in error:
  Foo_UnitTest.test_value:25->getFoo:33 ╗ IllegalState Invalid place to record e...

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0

Agent failed to start!
Exception in thread "Attach Listener"
```

So I conclude that `-javaagent` is somehow required. Confusing: When using eclipse to run the test it works like a charm!

The `jmockit-1.20.0.jar` which is passed to `-javaagent` and therefore is used to run the tests is exactly the same as the one in the eclipse repository. I also added `@RunWith(JMockit.class)` to the test. As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4369038/2318387), I used all three methods.

So do you have any clue what I can do?

Comment: try adding `-noverify` (for Java 8) or `-XX:-UseSplitVerifier` for Java 7 to turn off split verifier (Java options - might need to pass as <argument> into your test plugin)

Comment: @Jan When doing this, another error occurs which is the same as posted in [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32994290/2318387).

Comment: <!-- http://stackoverflow.com/a/4369038 -->
     <argLine>-javaagent:"D:\maven-test\org.jmockit_1.20.0.jar" -noverify -XX:-UseSplitVerifier</argLine> That how you did it?

Comment: I have only used `-noverify`. When I add `-XX...` the VM shows a warning to ignore it because Java 8 is used.

Comment: But still same output I suppose? Could you update with results you get now?

Comment: @Jan The error I got with `-noverify` is stored in [this file](https://github.com/ChristophLu/maventest/blob/master/error.txt)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96685/discussion-between-jan-and-christoph).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution: If I execute the tests in Eclipse using `Run As -> JUnit Test`, all works fine. If I execute the tests using `Run As -> JUnit Plugin Test`, the same error occurs. Researching gives no result and the support by JMockit is [cancelled](https://github.com/jmockit/jmockit1/issues/242) ("won't fix").

Since the "normal" tests are working perfectly I'm able to use the "normale" maven-surefire-plugin instead of the tycho-surefire-plugin. The only difference is the test phase (`test` instead of `integration-test`) and that there is no OSGi environment (which I do not need). Solution in POM files is as follows.

parent.pom

```
<project
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>...</groupId>
    <artifactId>...</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <tycho-version>0.24.0</tycho-version>
        <junit-version>4.11</junit-version>
        <maven-surefire-version>2.19</maven-surefire-version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${tycho-version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
                <version>${tycho-version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Tell tycho where to find the *.target file. -->
                    <target>
                        <artifact>
                            <groupId>...</groupId>
                            <artifactId>...</artifactId>
                            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                        </artifact>
                    </target>

                    <environments>
                        <environment>
                            <os>win32</os>
                            <ws>win32</ws>
                            <arch>x86_64</arch>
                        </environment>
                    </environments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>tycho-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${tycho-version}</version>
                <!-- we need to disable the tycho surefire plugin because it
                     runs an integration test. You can simulate it in Eclipse 
                     by executing a "JUnit Plugin test". This is not about to 
                     work with JMockit. Fortunately we do not need OSGi for 
                     the tests so we simply skip this phase. -->
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-test</id>
                        <phase>none</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Plugin to update the pom.xml to match the data found in MANIFEST.MF -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>tycho-versions-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${tycho-version}</version>
            </plugin>

            <!-- to run tests in test plugins -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-surefire-version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <testClassesDirectory>target/classes</testClassesDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <modules>
        <!-- ... -->
    </modules>
</project>
```

All other POM files then have the same structure:

```
<project
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>...</artifactId>
    <packaging>eclipse-plugin</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>...</groupId>
        <artifactId>...</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>...</relativePath>
    </parent>
</project>
```

Works perfectly! :)